# Binary file permissions issue

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, openvpn, vpn, binary

I've been facing an issue with NordVPN binary installation after I compiled a package and install it at the end it says *processing changes...* and then `cannot remove /var/lib/nordvpn/data/insights.dat operation is not permitted` and also the same with the `servers.dat` so when I run the following commands:

```
sudo chattr -i -a '/var/lib/nordvpn/data/insights.dat'
sudo chattr -i -a '/var/lib/nordvpn/data/servers.dat'
sudo chmod ugo+w '/var/lib/nordvpn/data/insights.dat'
sudo chmod ugo+w '/var/lib/nordvpn/data/servers.dat'
```

The installation works with no issues but after it is finished the permissions are locked/changed again and if I want to upgrade it the error comes back then I have to apply permissions again.

This is `nordvpn.install` file:

```
post_install() {
  echo ':: In order to enable nordvpn you have to start the following service:'
  echo '     sudo systemctl enable --now nordvpnd'
}

pre_remove() {
  chattr -i /var/lib/nordvpn/data/*
}
```

There's nothing much to it. I even tried to remove the `pre_remove` option but no success.

Comment: I would file a bug report to the package provider. If they have chattr -i for package removal, that implies they know they did chattr +i somewhere, so they have to deal with it everywhere

Comment: Probably a point thanks. I will try to contact them.